# how to achieve resizability in javafx?

Tags: java, javafx

I have an AncharPane in which all components are placed/designed using Fxml but the problem is, when the frame resize all components are stick with its current position.

Comment: that's behaving as designed - please read the java doc before using a layout (actually, before using every class :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `AnchorPane`, you can't get automatic resizing unless you have to resize your views one by one in the controller/code.

If you want autoresize, use `BorderPane`, `VBox` or `HBox`.

Answer (score 0):

If you're **using scene builder** you can achieve this by selecting the component you'd like to make resizable, then go under **layout** and set the **constraints**.
[image: A Preview]

You can also achieve this in your **Controller** class like this:

```
AnchorPane.setTopAnchor(yourTextField, 35);
AnchorPane.setLeftAnchor(yourTextField, 27);
AnchorPane.setRightAnchor(yourTextField, 120);
```

**I used a TextField for this example, but you can do it with other components.**

Answer (score -1):

If the AnchorPane has a border and padding set, the offsets will be measured from the inside edge of those insets.
To autoresize I recommend **BorderPane**. You can also use VBox and HBox to organize you Scene.